# what does it mean "set up for takeaways"?

Tags: word-usage

in an USA crime drama, when the detectives go to some market planning to wait and ambush a suspect, they (on radio) give command to local police, saying "Don't move untill suspect identified......I want all these exits covered and set up for takeaways". So, I guess takeaways mean those food-selling trucks? Does he want local police to allocate some of those trucks at exits and pretend to be selling food? Or just keep an eye on those trucks, but why he says "set up" instead of "all 
 these exits and takeaways covered"?

Comment: I'm suspecting you may have misheard it.

Comment: Doubtful. Nobody in the US says takeaway.

Comment: Thanks for fast response. It's articulate, and clear written in subtitle. And I watched this part carefully, there's no food truck. Suspect bought a rifle and some ammo, maybe that's "takeaways"?----ambush is in parking lot outside

Comment: Maybe a "takeaway" is when they arrest someone and take them away.  So the instructions say they should be ready ("set up") to do that at any exit.

Comment: Just as point of note, a lot of subtitles are computer generated with speech recognition software and are very prone to error.

Comment: It seems to be from an episode of [*Chicago P.D.*](https://transcripts.foreverdreaming.org/viewtopic.php?f=83&t=14987) From the script for the show: "Rosemont PD, in position and ready to move in. Rosemont PD, stand down, stand down. We will wait for the suspect to be identified. 
I want all these exits covered and set up for takeaways. Maintain eyes on the vehicle. Well... Talk about the worst place in the world to take down a suspect, right?"

Comment: @JasonBassford - That's not a "script", that's a "transcript".  See Jim's comment.

Comment: Well, thanks everybody! Appreciate it.

Comment: @JasonBassford Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Takeaways are people whom plain clothes police officers approach, identify themselves, and ask the people to leave the area (sometimes escorted, sometimes not). The purpose is to depopulate the area so they can surround and surprise the suspect without putting additional people in jeopardy.

The [whole conversation](https://www.wattpad.com/619193728-detective-ln-an-adam-ruzek-love-story-at-least):

> Later that day, we headed to a **convention center** in Rosemont where there was a connection to us finding Tony's body. "Rosemont PD, in position and ready to move in" someone said over the radio. "Rosemont PD, stand down, stand down. We will wait for the suspect to be identified. I want all these exits covered and set up for takeaways. Maintain eyes on the vehicle" Voight said into the radio. "**Well, talk about the worst place in the world to take down a suspect**, right" Adam said.
>
> "Olinsky, can you I.D. Sims: Voight asked. "Yeah, **on his way out**, and he's got a brand-new shiny akm" Al said. "All right, **nobody pops off until Sims gets the artillery into his vehicle**, he's out of this parking lot. **We'll just box him in**. Patrol, position to the front" Voight spoke. "Suspect unarmed. Moving in" someone said into the radio. That's when a Rosemont police car rolled into the lot. "He's jumping the gun" I say and take the radio from Voight. "Rosemont PD, pull back! Pull back, Rosemont!" But they didn't listen and got out of the car. "Stop! Police" a Rosemont cop shouted. That's when Sims pulled out a gun and people started screaming.
>
> I ducked behind a car just as Sims started shooting at the police. "**Watch your aim**" Voight shouted. I popped up and started shooting at Sims again, but he ducked behind his car. A Rosemont police officer ran to take cover, and Sims shot him a few times in the back. There was no way I was going to let him bleed out, so I ran from my hiding spot towards him. "Um wait" Adam shouted. I slid into the snow next to the officer just as Sims ran off.
>
> I felt for a pulse, and there was one, but it was faint. "We have an officer down. Roll an ambo to the Rosemont Gun Convention. Shots fired by the police. **Plain clothes officers at the scene**." I put pressure on the wounds, but there was not much that I could do. The ambo then came and took the cop away. Then we all headed back to the district. "The Rosemont police officer who was shot died on the way to the hospital. Wife, two kids. We lost that guy. So we go down whatever dark hole we have to to find Sims" Voight said.

Comment: Thank you,sir. Your answer sounds reasonable, but I can not see that meaning from the whole conversation? And, "Plain clothes officers at the scene"  I've seen this in many episodes of this drama when detectives call ambulence, maybe this sentence is to make ambulence identify them more easier and faster?

Comment: You could try replacing the word you are asking about with whatever suggestions you receive and see which you prefer. PS: I've owned a [scanner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.scannerradio) for over 10 years.